xfce4-power-manager doesn’t start automatically on boot in i3wm; I have to start it manually each time
I'm running i3wm under Fedora 41
in my i3 config file:
# start xfce4 settings daemon
exec --no-startup-id xfsettingsd
for_window [class="Xfce4-settings-manager"] focus, floating disable
exec --no-startup-id xfce4-power-manager


The power manager doesn't start on boot. I can manually launch it from the XFCE4 settings GUI or by running i3-msg exec xfce4-power-manager in the terminal, which works. However, I haven’t been able to get it to start automatically at boot.
Using i3-msg restart alone doesn’t execute the command. When I set the command as exec_always, followed by i3-msg restart, it does work. I also tried initializing it as a service and adding sleep 20 before the command in the i3 config, but neither method worked

Seems to me to be a near-duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/786747/321108
